# Linker error returned when compiling c++ program

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am writing  a program utilizing getline to read text from  a .txt file. I had compiled it about a week ago, and the program ran perfectly. When I tried to compile it again today, I received the below error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: getline: _ZSt4cout: invalid version 3 (max 0)
getline: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

        string text;
        ifstream readfrom;

        readfrom.open("read.txt");

        while(getline(readfrom, text)){

        cout << text << endl;

        }

        readfrom.close();

return 0;
}
```

Command utilized to compile program:

```
g++ getline.cpp -o getline
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You omitted the most important part:  the command you used to compile the code.

Comment: to execute your binary either use full pathname or the relative path to reach your executable to avoid possibility of accidently running a different binary with same name earlier in your PATH env var ... also to view linked libraries of your binary issue   ldd ./my_bin_name_here

Answer (score -1):

Update: Fixed the problem by moving code to new text file

Comment: This is not an answer, and should not be posted as one. It does not provide any useful information about solving a problem. If you've found that the issue was a corrupt or invalid file on your system, that information is not useful to others. You should delete your post instead.